# AWS Emails Sender-Verification Limit - An Email for each User

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

I am building an application that uses AWS for hosting. Additionally I use SES (Simple Email Service) to send emails. So far everything works fine.

**However the structure of my application requires me to generate emails (`someuser@mydomain.com`) and send messages from these addresses.**

AWS requires me to verify sender-email addresses, and even if I could do that programmatically, AWS still states that there can be **at most 10.000 verified email addresses** per AWS region - which is not going to suffice.

I am looking for a way to get my application working. Does anyone know if I can increase that limit? Or do you have any other suggestions, how I could implement this?

Clarification: Every user gets an address at my domain (user1234@mydomain.com) There is no problem verifying the domain

Comment: What kind of application (other than spam generator) would require this, just asking?

Comment: There are 10+ platforms in our area where you can sell your car. The idea of the application is that you register the car you want to sell once on our app, the app in turn spreads it to the 10+ platforms. Communication on these platforms works via email, so every car needs to have some sort of email.

(e. g. there is a small html form on each platform which sends an email to the specified address - the one we generated. In order to have proper communication messages sent via the 'chat' in our app are forwarded as emails from the generic address)

The platforms, are fine with it

Comment: The problem we are having with reply-to headers is, that there seem to be many clients out there which will just respond to the from header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *AWS requires me to verify sender-email addresses*

No, it doesn't.

> Amazon SES requires that you verify your email address **or domain**, to confirm that you own it and to prevent others from using it. **When you verify an entire domain, you are verifying all email addresses from that domain, so you don't need to verify email addresses from that domain individually.** *(emphasis added)*
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-domains.html